# "Full Name" field populated with e-mail address upon inviting a user

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Using Google Chrome, I tried to invite a user to join careers.stackoverflow.com. I was promptly informed that that e-mail address had already received an invitation. At that point, the "Full Name" field's value was overwritten with the rejected e-mail from the "Email address" field. Later on, when I sent an invitation to a different address, the invite succeeded and a new entry was added to the "Previously sent invitations" table. Unfortunately, the table replaced the user's name with his e-mail address (i.e. "john.doe@gmail.com <john.doe@gmail.com>").

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, fix coming shortly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Invitations now use the "Full Name" (if provided).